# Windows 7 DNS not working (nslookup IS working; ping -4 name.com NOT working)

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

## nslookup IS working; ping -4 name.com NOT working

The most obvious *symptom* of this problem is that `nslookup` IS working, while `ping -4 name.com` is NOT working.

That's because `nslookup` contains its own DNS client, and so does not use the Windows one.

`ping` when given a name, uses the Windows DNS Client to translate name -> number.

So if `nslookup` can translate, then lots of things work: networking hardware, NIC adapter driver, internet connectivity to the DNS servers, and successfully accessing the servers to do a translation. That's a lot!

However, `ping -4 name.com` fails, so if all that other stuff is working, it's the Windows DNS client software itself that is implicated.

Note i did `ping -4` to isolate to IPv4 excluding IPv6 influences.

## displaydns fails

That's why the best symptom to describe the *actual* problem is that

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

reports:

```
Could not display the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

### But DNS client is running

Reading forums, the most probable reason for this symptom is the DNS Client (aka `dnscache`) service is not running; however for us it is.

We did

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
sc query dnscache
```

and it is on.

### It's Not DNS suffix

Another possibility is that there are DNS suffixes in use.  However going into network and sharing center -> change adapter settings -> Wireless Network Connection -> Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4 Properties -> Advanced -> DNS tab, we have:

[CHECKED] Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes

- [CHECKED] Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix

[UNchecked] Append these DNS suffixes

(and the list box is empty)

DNS suffix for this connection:

[CHECKED] Register this connection's addresses in DNS
[UNchecked] Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration.

However, i'm not sure if any of this matters cuz we can't get to goolge.com, ie a FQDN.

## More info

We disabled IPv6 for now for debug.  So everything reported in here is with IPv6 off.

`nslookup` works reliably, on `google.com` and everything else.

However,

```
ping -4 google.com
```

says

```
Ping request could not find host google.com
```

And browsing says DNS error.

Now, I have learned that `nslookup` has its own DNS client, separate from Windows. Which would lead me to believe that `nslookup's` DNS client is fine, and Windows is corrupted somehow.

Indeed, we can browse google and other sites via IP address fine, just not by name.

`ping` by IP address works fine. As does `tracert` by IP address.

### Not DirectAccess

The problem does not appear to be DirectAccess :

```
netsh dns show state
```

reports (among other things)

```
Network Location Behavior           Never use Direct Access settings

Direct Access Settings              Not Configured
```

### Wireshark

A Wireshark capture during `nslookup` shows name queries.

However a capture doing ping showed no such queries. In fact, no activity at all (other than background). That suggests that the Windows DNS client is not even trying to go out to the internet and translate the name, which would be consistent with its inability to displaydns.

### Other notes

The `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` is empty (only comments).

The problem happens when the DNS server is set to the university's; or when set to google's 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 and/or OpenDNS's 208.67.222.222 and/or 208.67.220.220. Which makes sense given that Wireshark reports that Windows isn't even sending the name query.

The problem happened after a heat crash. However, being able to browse by IP rules hardware problems, except perhaps for HDD corruption. However `chkdsk` did not report any bad sectors, and `sfc` did not find any corruption.

We have also uninstalled the Network Adapter in Device Manager and let it re-install automatically. Also checked for updates for this adapter on windows. There weren't any.

The crash means a reboot, so maybe it was a bad windows update. However, there were several reboots before this one and after the most recent windows update.

We've run for rootkit is Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, also their Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit beta, TDSSKiller, and Comodo Cleaning Essentials (CCE, but it appears not to be updated).

Have not tried in safe mode with networking yet.

We are mostly using a university router, however the problem also happens when connected to smartphone's hotspot.

`ipconfig` reports 5 Tunnel Adapters, but they all report "Media Disconnected".  2 of them look university specific.

`ipconfig` and device manager both report a `Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter`. What is this and could it be the problem?

The problem is identical after many reboots of the PC.

It's a laptop, and most of this was done with the wireless connection, but the wired connection appeared to have the same behavior.

## Summary

So, it appears Windows DNS client is corrupted or at least malfunctioning in some way, but I'm not sure how to figure out why.

(BTW, i'm writing this on another computer)

## Edit:

@Kris wanted to see `ipconfig /all`

```
C:\Users\[username]>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . :       <<<====NOTE NO HOST NAME
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ed*****.***l.edu

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ed*****.***l.edu
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.131.2.**(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.128.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, April 27, 2015 11:32:13 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, April 27, 2015 11:47:13 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.131.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 132.236.56.249
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.35.82.50
                                       128.253.180.2
                                       132.236.56.250
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : r****.****l.edu
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {CBE4B55D-63C6-460A-82CF-7076427CD2AF}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.e****.****l.edu:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{270C639B-82A2-4AE7-B886-D40DAA7EF798}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.r****.****l.edu:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

## Edit 2:

Tried

```
netsh int ip set dns "wireless network connection" static 8.8.4.4
net winsock reset
```

and reboot and did not change anything.

Tried this excellent site (thanks @Kris) [Windows 7: Services - Restore Default Services in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236709-services-restore-default-services-windows-7-a.html)  and downloaded their `DNS_Client.reg` (and named it `.reg.txt` for safety) and compared that to the existing registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache` but sadly, they were the same.

Comment: The PC is remote from me (the superuser account holder) and obviously has no internet. I have a picture of the screen.  I can post that, i guess, soon. In the meantime, what are you looking for?

Comment: The actual network configuration, as to if there might be something blocking it or in any way malfunctioning.

Comment: Try this command ;

netsh int ip set dns 
                                                                                                                  netsh winsock reset

Comment: @vembutech I can't do this right now, but I have a question: are you suggesting setting some DNS servers with that command? Or with no parameters it somehow resets to defaults. We have done this using the GUI, trying university DNS via automatic, and trying google and OpenDNS (as i said in OP). Does setting DNS servers via cmd line help more than via GUI? We have tried the winsock reset, but perhaps not immediately after setting a new DNS server.

Comment: @vembutech Thanks for the attention, but I'm gonna have to down-vote your response. Reasons: Your command is really 2 commands. `netsh int ip set dns` as written is incomplete, but I already explained how I manipulate DNS, and gui vs cmd line doesnt matter, so your suggestion adds nothing. I tried setting DNS anyway and doing `netsh winsock reset` but it didnt work. If you at least explain(ed) yourself, I would not down-vote you. But as it stands, I must. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Kris. Did you see that II posted the ipconfig /all output (we got the text; better anyway). See anything? I don't. Unless it's one of those adapters.

Comment: Well some of all the tunnel interfaces could be creating havoc somewhere, but they all seem to be in a disconnect state. Could you try deleting the interface and rebooting to see if that maybe fixes it? You can do it in device manager. Also try to disable all unneeded interfaces.

Comment: @Kris already tried deleting (uninstalling) the interface (network adapter or NIC) in device manager. Windows auto-re-installs them. Did not try rebooting _immediately_ after, but have rebooted many times since then. Did not help. If you read my post, i've tried just about everything. Notice that nslookup still works. As does browsing ti IP addresses. So I think i've narrowed it down to a corruption of the windows DNS client. Everything else checks out. Not sure how to debug that component specifically.

Comment: Well then my last suggestion is this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/dns-look-up-fails-how-do-i-fix-it/36934cd0-5ac3-418c-82dd-5cb3bea86607
Or this: http://www.wintips.org/how-to-restore-windows-services-to-their-default-state/
Windows unfortunately doesn't really believe in repairing their native services easily, but you might somehow be able to uninstall or repair the DNS service.

Comment: @Kris not the wintips link itself, but it pointed to [Windows 7: Services - Restore Default Services in Windows 7 <sevenforums>](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/236709-services-restore-default-services-windows-7-a.html) which is a killer post which I had not seen before. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We found the answer [on edugeek.com](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/80223-dns-resolver-issues-nslookup-works-ping-doesnt.html) and used it as a guide. Our explicit actions are explained below.

The answer on EduGeek is first introduced in [post 13 by shoeib](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/80223-dns-resolver-issues-nslookup-works-ping-doesnt.html#post712664) who says they got it from that thread, but I see nothing in that thread up to that point that would even hint at that answer.

[Post 20 by fencecat42](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/80223-dns-resolver-issues-nslookup-works-ping-doesnt-2.html#post1077593) goes into more detail.

Specifically,

In registry key:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

The following "values" (as MS confusingly terms them, each of which can have "data") are *missing*

```
Domain
Hostname
NV Hostname
```

All three were missing on both fencecat42's and our system.

Now, kudos (well, almost ;) @Kris because **there was evidence of this problem in the `ipconfig /all` that they asked me to post.** Notice in my posted output there is no `Host Name`. This is one and the same `Hostname` from the registry.

I am hesitant to edit the registry, because one stray keystroke could make your system unbootable, in which case hopefully you have made a system restore or made a copy of your registry (my favorite ways are ERUNT and Tweaking.com Windows Repair All-In-One (which includes a registry save tool) (I found out about these tools at techsupportalert.com))

So to set the `Hostname`, we simply went into Control Panel -> System. (Often the "Change Settings" link is not visible in the first screen; you have to scroll down. This step requires UAC authorization. After setting it you have to reboot.)

This action sets *both* the `Hostname` and `NV Hostname` "values" in the registry.

We could not find a non-regedit way of editing the `Domain` "value". (Maybe `netdom` but we didn't have this on this Windows 7 Home Premium system.) So we used the registry to set `Domain` **to an empty value**. We used `regedit`, navigated to the `Tcpip/Parameters` key, right click -> New -> String Value. That creates a new "value" and sets you up to type its name, changing the default new name. Then **we did not have to create an actual "data" for this "value"** (again pardon MS's counter-intuitive terms). Just created it and left its "data" uninitialized.

Note: we tried networking after setting JUST the Hostname's. Did not work. the `Domain` (even empty) was required. We did not try with Domain created (and empty) but without creating and setting the Hostname's. But I think that's an interesting experiment.

## Reflections

First,

I don't remember now, but I suspect we tried [Microsoft's "How to reset TCP/IP by using the NetShell utility"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357) which is

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
```

(or whatever path and filename you want for the log file).

And that MS page says this:

> When you run the reset command, it overwrites the following registry keys, both of which are used by TCP/IP:
>
> ```
> SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters 
> SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters
> ```
>
> [Seems like the same registry key we changed, MS is just not showing all of its hierarchy. --john v kumpf]
>
> This has the same effect as removing and reinstalling TCP/IP. To run the manual command successfully, you must specify a name for the log file in which the netsh actions will be recorded. (This log file is referred to as "resetlog.txt" in the manual procedures earlier in this section.)

Perhaps, this reinstall process overwrites those registry keys, and *fails to write the Hostname's and Domain*? Maybe?

If so, then what really worked for us is doing the MS ip reset, THEN setting those registry keys.

Second,

Our problem appeared after rebooting after a crash due to heat. Hard to connect that event to the problem. One possibility is that the heat crashed a small number of blocks of the disk and one of those block happened to be holding part of the Tcpip registry key values. Unlikely, but I guess possible.

Or, if that re-installing TCP/IP *was* necessary, that the disk blocks corrupted the TCP/IP service, and we had to re-install it and then fix it up after.

Third,

This is quite an interesting result. What this means is that the Windows DNS Client looks for either `Domain` or 2 or all 3 of these "values" in the registry. And if it finds it (them), it's fine. If it doesn't find them, specifically if it does not find the `Domain`, it errors out and simply fails. No error report [1].

I think we can conclude from this evidence that **this is a bug in the Windows DNS Client**. We can prove this because it works with an **empty** Domain value, that means the software can't really be using it, which means why would it require it to exist (even empty) to function properly? That's a bug.

[1]Fourth,

There *might* have been an error report, but not in the Event Viewer in the common places (under the hierarchy: Event Viewer (Local) -> Windows -> Application, and System). There are other logs, many not turned on by default, that might have had some output, especially

- Event Viewer (Local)
- - Applications and Services Local
- - - Microsoft
- - - - Windows
- - - - - DNS Client Events
- - - - - - Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Admin
- - - - - - Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Operational

but also possibly

- Event Viewer (Local)
- - Applications and Services Local
- - - Microsoft
- - - - Windows
- - - - - Dhcp* -> *
- - - - - Diagnostics-Networking -> Operational
- - - - - Iphlpsvc -> Operational
- - - - - NCSI -> Operational
- - - - - NDIS -> Operational
- - - - - Network Access Protection
- - - - - - Operational
- - - - - - WHC
- - - - - NetworkProfile -> Operational
- - - - - NlaSvc -> Operational
- - - - - NTLM -> Operational
- - - - - WebIO -> NDF/Diagnostic
- - - - - Winsock Catalog Change -> Operational
- - - - - Winsock Network Event -> Operational
- - - - - Wired-AutoConfig -> Operational
- - - - - WLAN-AutoConfig -> Operational

Fifth,

After MANY hours surfing this problem, it seems this problem is usually hard to debug and is something "weird".

For example in [this post at spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/270104-can-nslookup-hostname-but-ping-can-t-find-host), the problem was an expired certificate in a DNS server.

[Poster "Galen in Laguna" at spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/1937098) suggested a way to completely uninstall the TCP/IP stack in Windows 7 and let Windows reinstall it. I suspect that would have worked in our case, because it would have restored the `Tcpip` registry key. (But see the MS post above.)

[Poster ILS at spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/1942335) suggested that the `afd.sys` driver might have a Trojan or be corrupted in some way, and suggested how to replace it. (`afd` stands for "Ancillary function driver" for Winsock.)

This superuser post [Why is 'ping' unable to resolve a name when 'nslookup' works fine?](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine) where the question had 35 upvotes and the best answer 27, is a good reference. There, people reported "other solutions for them" including:

- multiple default gateways
- two PC's having the same IP address on the network
- Windows 7 Multi Label DNS Query issue (whatever that is)

Also, people report this problem can be caused by "rootkits". I would suggest anyone struggling with this problem to run a few rootkit scanner/removers. bleepingcomputer.com is a good place to get advice. Or read [Gizmo's Best Free Rootkit Scanner/Remover at techsupportalert.com](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-rootkit-scanner-remover.htm)

Sixth,

There's evidence in forums that this problem goes unsolved most often.

[One of those posters, "Galen in Laguna", at spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/post/1937098) said that's what they usually have to do.

That same superuser post [Why is 'ping' unable to resolve a name when 'nslookup' works fine?](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine) where the question had 35 upvotes and the best answer 27, the best answer author said, **"Some sites also recommend uninstalling and reinstalling SP3 in this case."**

And, [This poor superuser who tried everything, got no answer, and after 18 days had to repair install](https://superuser.com/questions/813716/all-internet-browsers-wont-resolve-dns-except-for-torbrowser)

Seventh,

Helpful hint if this does not solve *your* problem: When searching the internet for Windows DNS problems, be aware that a lot of posts are talking about a Windows *server functioning as a DNS server*. Our issue was that we had a plain old PC connected via a router to the internet and our DNS *client* software was not working. Sometimes reading posts I missed that distinction.

Eighth,

Another helpful hint if you go searching: many problems of this sort we found posted had attributes we did NOT have:

1. local DNS server within the building (ours was public DNS server, eg, google's 8.8.8.8).
2. failure to translate names of local nodes within the building (we were trying to access public internet sites, like www.google.com)
3. part of a Windows domain and/or using Active Directory, eg in a corporate environment (we just had our PC connected to a wireless router)

I hope our answer helps someone else.

Comment: I love you so, so much ! For me, just setting the laptop's hostname fixed it (I did not touch the domain). Using the new windows 10 shiny settings screen did not work however (it kept saying the host name was not valid). But using the good old Control Panel > System and security > System > Change settings (in "Computer name ...") did the trick. I'm still amazed how such a weird behavior (no internet access, some app crashing, nslookup OK but no DNS resolution...) can be fixed by such a simple action...

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall all network drivers and set a static dns to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google primary and secondary dns servers).

Comment: If you read the (admittedly long) OP, you'll see i already tried both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the DNS cache using:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

If that fails it might be worth a shot checking the DNS Client service by starting services.msc from the command prompt. Find the service called "DNS Client" and make sure it's start method is set to "Automatic" and that the service is started.

Comment: You'll see in my (admittedly long--but this was the point) OP that the problem persists after reboot. Reboot (among other things) flushes the DNS cache.

Also, note the very first thing in my OP: "displaydns fails". Thus, the DNS client cache software is not even functioning correctly, it's not that that software is functioning correctly and the contents of the database it manages contains corrupt entries, which might be fixed by flushdns.

Also, again note that I reported in the OP that "DNS client is running" using the command line (which reports the same thing as `services.msc`)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall TCP/IP (please continue reading...). I don't mean "reset it", "restart it", "re-enable it".
In Windows 10 run "netcfg -u ms_tcp". This will IN FACT remove the protocol from your system. No more TCP/IP v4 on it.
Reinstall the protocol the usual way (properties of network connection; add protocol).
In windows 7 you could edit nettcpip.inf to allow you to unistall the protocol from the network connection properties, but that is not possible in Windows 10 (can't say in 8 nor 8.1).
Hope this helps someone. RV

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, my registry seems fine, the only way to fix temporally this problem is to launch : `ipconfig /renew`. 
I'll try to reset the IP stack, I'll post some more info if I find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. For us it was related to the uninstallation of OpenVPN Connect. Following the next steps resolved our problem:

1. Installed OpenVPN Connect again.
2. Disabled / Unchecked DNS Fallback from the OpenVPN Connect Icon.
3. Uninstalled OpenVPN again.
4. Rebooted the computer.

Hopefully this helps.