# Windows 10 can't resolve hostnames - ping with IP works but not with hostname

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ip, ping

Facts:

1. The browser doesn't load any pages, whether they are addressed with IP or hostname.
2. `ping google.com` doesn't work, returning `Ping request could not find host google.com.`
3. `ping 216.58.209.78` (google IP) does work, sending and receiving all packets.
4. `nslookup google.com` does work, returning correct IP address that then does indeed work with `ping`.
5. Network settings are default, IP and DNS are set to auto.
6. Specifying OpenDNS in network settings does not help.
7. There are no entries in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host`
8. There are no DNS prefixes in use.
9. `netsh winsock reset & netsh int ip reset` does not help.
10. DNS client is running.
11. The most common given solution on the Internet `ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /registerdns` does not work, with latter returning `Registration of DNS records failed: Parameter is not correct.` It happens occassionally to people, but I have not found possible solutions to this problem. I sense this might be the key to my ordeal.
12. All of the above happens for different networks.
13. The PC has been recently formatted. One guy had the same problem and it helped to restore the previous PC name, but I have no way of finding what the name was before the format.
14. `ipconfig /all` is as below. The first paragraph looks a bit blank, perhaps something there...?

    ```
    Windows IP Configuration

       Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 
       Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
       Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
       IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
       WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

    Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2C-60-0C-9B-A8-89
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    Wireless LAN adapter PoĄczenie lokalne* 2:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AE-E0-10-65-58-B9
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

    Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta sieciowa Broadcom 802.11n
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-E0-10-65-58-B9
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::fc42:138f:fb5a:f6ff%12(Preferred) 
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.172(Preferred) 
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 21 grudnia 2015 22:16:55
       Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 28 grudnia 2015 22:21:43
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
       DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 217.172.224.160
                                           192.168.0.1
       NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

    Tunnel adapter isatap.{9E3DA69D-E183-4041-9944-35B59277B529}:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
       Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
       Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
       DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
       Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    ```

    15. Setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 doesn't work, see replies to suggestions beneath.
    16. It doesn't resolve local hostnames either. The machine doesn't respond to pings from local network.

Any ideas how to proceed? Help my dad enjoy his internet!

Comment: Is static IP and DNS working? From where are you getting DHCP info? Can you check you DHCP server configuration?

Comment: If 192.168.0.1 is your router then try to remove 192.168.0.1 from its DNS servers... I guess that 217.172.224.160 is valid DNS server and just rejects external requests. Have you tried setup OpenDNS on your DHCP server?

Comment: You indicate that nslookup works. What is the name of the DNS server being queried? That may provide you with some hint as to where your system is getting it's information and allow you to make corrections...if it does not match your expected output. Jeremys-iMac:~ jeremy$ nslookup google.com
**Server: 2001:4860:4860::8888
Address: 2001:4860:4860::8888#53** Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 216.58.216.14

Comment: Hi, g2mk. OP here. I tried to follow your line of thought with some google-fu. Static IP and DNS do not work, I can tell that for sure. As for DHCP, I'm not sure how to reply to these questions. It is a standard and public-available DSL service supplied by one of the local Internet providers. Is DHCP on my side of things, or is it theirs? I tried following http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/jcwarner/archive/2011/06/27/collect-dhcp-information-from-the-command-prompt/ to get some info on my DHCP, but it doesn't recognize `show server` command. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but it might be worth using `&&` in commands instead of `&`.  The latter will try and run the commands simultaneously, which might prevent one or more of them working. `&&` will run the second command only after the first command has finished, and if it doesn't return with an error code.

Answer (score 3):

a. You can try to manually set the dns servers to the google ones: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

b. You can try another wireless adapter

c. You can try a linux live cd and verify if the issues are still present

Comment: a. It didn't work. See my other replies for more detail. b. It didn't work with another wireless adapter and ethernet cable.

Comment: @user2551153 please try a linux live cd/usb (using the wired connection if possible), since your issue is strange enough to make me think of viruses/firewalls/group policy settings.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this same issue on a Windows 10 Dell tablet that one of my users brought into the office. Same issue, communications via IP work, but name resolution not working (aside from nslookup, oddly that was working fine).

After digging into this for a few minutes I also discovered that the tablet was missing a hostname entry when doing an ipconfig /all (same as shown in your screenshot above), so I went into the System properties and found that there was no computer name set in there. Added a computer name, rebooted, et voila! Name resolution is now working properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the hostname was present. In addition, running `ipconfig /flushdns` would hang. Changing the hostname by adding a 2 to the end and then rebooting seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had these symptoms two or three times in the past after installing a new NIC or router, using WinXP and Win7. Solutions varied, but **in one case the issue was resolved by unticking the "use NetBIOS over TCP" box**. In the other case I remember having to run some unusual command line utility (not *ipconfig /flushdns*; something else that I don't quite recall) to flush cached somethingsomethingsomething.
One thing I'd check is whether local (LAN side) hostnames resolve ok. If it's only WAN side hostnames that don't resolve properly then at least you know the problem is not on your PC.

Comment: Hi. I tried playing with 'use NetBIOS over TCP'. I don't know which unusual command line utility you refer to, but google often points to `nbtstat -R` or `nbtstat -RR` in this case. I tried each and it didn't change a thing. I also tried to restart the computer (does that clear the cache you refer to? I don't know. But just in case...). It doesn't resolve local hostnames either. On an interesting side-note : it doesn't respond to local pings either.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have hyper-v manager installed and has one virtual switch that bridges my NIC with it. Try disabling/removing the virtual switch in hyper-v manager (elevated user needed). This one works for me. Maybe Windows 10 or hyper-v has a buggy virtual switch.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the computer was recently reformatted could indicate a problem with the drivers for your network adapter(s).

Open "View network connections" and try disabling each adapter one-by-one.  After disabling each one, test the DNS and then re-enable it.  Perhaps you'll find one that's causing your DNS problems - if you do, you could try reinstalling the driver for that particular adapter.

Comment: It has to be a DNS problem. If you can ping the IP but it doesn't resolve, that's got to be the issue.

Comment: Agreed, but DNS goes through the network adapter.  It's entirely possible that the driver for the network adapter has a bug that's interfering with DNS.  I was particularly suspicious of the "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" in your ipconfig dump.  It's Microsoft-made, but I'm not clear on what it actually does.

Comment: Hi, man. OP here. I tried doing as you said, but all entries I see under 'view network connections' are: Ethernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller) and Wi-Fi (Network card Broadcom 802.11n). There was no Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter or anything else. I disabled / re-enabled both of them : the first one didn't really change a thing, and the second one was wi-fi so there was no connection whatsoever. I also tried following steps on http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-adapter#1TC=windows-7 but it produced same results.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting the host name was not enough - it didn't help. What was missing is the Domain entry in the registry at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain` also.

I have no idea how did it happen to my PC, maybe after some system crash or during the recovery the entry went missing. (Because there were some problems and I did recover my system with dism and sfc.)

So after I created this registry entry (just with the empty value) - it started working immediately even without reboot. It took me many hours and I tried probably everything I could google out until I finally bumped on the answer here - [Windows 7 DNS not working (nslookup IS working; ping -4 name.com NOT working)](https://superuser.com/questions/906555/windows-7-dns-not-working-nslookup-is-working-ping-4-name-com-not-working).

Answer (score -1):

All the things suggested by other posters failed, so I resorted to drastic measures and did a full format with a fresh Win 10 install. It did work.

Comment: That's like "healing the disease by killing the patient". This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree. It's just that none of the suggestions worked and I did check each of them diligently. I'm sorry we couldn't reach a fruitful conclusion.