# Windows 10 DNS Name Resolution Stops Working - But Nslookup Works

Tags: networking, windows-10

My Windows 10 laptop has been experiencing a weird issue where the Wifi connects but I cannot access the Internet.  When it starts, there's nothing I can do but restore Windows from backup or re-install Windows.

`nslookup` on Command Prompt works fine, I get DNS name resolution.  But, `ping` or web browser or anything fails to resolve a DNS name.  They sit, wait, and timeout with a DNS resolution error.

Tried flushing the DNS cache, re-installing the network driver, resetting the winsock driver, flushing the route table, re-connecting to wifi, specifying static DNS server IPs, switching Wifi networks, tethering through my phone, and rebooting. Nothing works.

Doubt it's a hardware issue, since re-installing Windows or restoring from a recent backup fixes the issue... at least until it happens again a few weeks/months later.  Also tried disabling the onboard Wifi and plugging in a separate USB wifi adapter, same result.

Anyone have any thoughts? What would cause, and how to fix?

I've been making frequent full-system backups in the event this occurs again, I restore from backup and all is fine.  Only thing I can think that changed around the time the issue began was I got a displaylink USB hub/display adapter for a third monitor.

Comment: Try another OS as a test, for a while. Run Ubuntu from a USB drive the next time connection fails, to confirm that it is OS and not HW.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure it's not the hardware because yes, booting to another OS works fine.  If I boot to Windows "safe mode (with networking)" it works fine.  Boot back into Windows, and nslookup works but everything else fails to resolve DNS.  If I re-install Windows or restore from a recent Windows backup, everything works again, until the next time it happens.

Comment: Does reinstallation from MS ISO, made with the Media Creation Tool, pose the same issue? Could it be a failed malware installation that is stuck in both the disk image and on the machine? Try a single (not permanent) malware scan with an alternative tool, such as Kaspersky Security Scan.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows from scratch (from the Media Creation Tool) fixes the problem.  Also, restoring from a backup fixes the problem.  I have tried Antivirus 
 and spyware scans, but not Kaspersky.

Comment: Just a thought, i wonder if my problems are caused by frequent switching of wifi networks? Sometimes the Wifi which my windows boots to is not the one I want, so I switch. Each have different SSIDs, passwords, and networks. Then maybe after a reboot, something gets stuck and I cannot unlock/flush it. I dunno, just a thought on behavior that I do which may not be common.

Comment: Have you tried setting DNS resolution to a fixed provider, such as CloudFlare, https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-1111/ , rather than let the ISP set it automatically? At least that would not change, though ISP does.

Comment: Thanks but yes, tried changing DNS server to a fixed public DNS address rather than the auto-assigned one from DHCP.  Tried several, not 1.1.1.1 but 8.8.8.8, 74.82.42.42, and 4.2.2.1.  Same result- name resolutions works with `nslookup` on command prompt but ping, web and everything else times out resolving.  Haven't had the issue in the last few weeks after the last time I re-installed Windows (fingers crossed) but I did install fewer software this time around, thinking that may help.

Comment: I now think the issue is with Windows itself. The issue happened again - wifi stopped working, while connected, nslookup works but everything else fails to resolve DNS.  I restored from a 1 week-old backup, and the problem did not go away like it had before. Even though Wifi worked a week ago, it did not. This backup had all recent Windows updates, while in the past, my backups did not have recent Windows updates. So, I re-installed Windows from scratch (Media Creation Tool) and the Wifi started working again.  I wonder if the latest Windows updates has something which breaks Wifi permanently.

Comment: Windows 10 v. 1903 appears to be a work-in-progress. v. 1809 appears to be reasonably stable, at this time, and if you have continued difficulties, stick with that 9or earlier) versions.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on my Windows 10 laptop. I probably tried everything I could find in the net - nothing helped. Until finally I bumped on this - [Windows 7 DNS not working (nslookup IS working; ping -4 name.com NOT working)](https://superuser.com/questions/906555/windows-7-dns-not-working-nslookup-is-working-ping-4-name-com-not-working)

I tried to set the hostname before, it was probably the 1st thing I tried, but it did not help. In the answer by the link above they mention that the `Domain` record must be set also in the registry, at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`. It was missing. So after I created it manually with `regedit` (with just an empty string value since my PC wasn't in a domain, apparently it's the only way to restore it) - it immediately started working even without reboot.

Comment: Excellent post and glad you found a fix. I will try this next time it happens.